# Copy command not working "Batch Programming"

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Want to make a installer for a game i play:

```
@echo off
echo.
echo Choose One
echo __________
echo.
echo 32        
echo.           
echo 64        
echo.           
echo Idk       
echo.           
echo __________
echo.
echo.
set/p bit=
goto %bit%

:32
xcopy "warcraft3" C:\Program Files
pause
goto done

:64
xcopy "warcraft3" C:\Program Files(x86)
pause
goto done

:idk
xcopy "warcraft3" C:\Program Files
pause
goto done

:done
```

the "warcraft3" is a folder not a zip or anything, it says it cant find the specified file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need quotes around folders with spaces

```
xcopy "warcraft3" "C:\Program Files\"
```

also good practice to put a trailing slash on destination folders.

Comment: In the 'data' folder there is a folder called warcraft3. it will not copy that folder to the programfiles, but if i make a text document in the data folder it copies that but not the folder. i need it to copy the folder

Comment: Use `"warcraft\*.*"` and if you want to copy subdirectories then add  /s/h/e/k/f/c to the end